# How to fetch a image from online(http) and make it as a wallpaper using Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, desktop-background

I need to change the background of my desktop in Ubuntu 12. 04 with a command in terminal, in order to make a script with bash. Does anyone know how to do it? but i want the image from internet...

i know if i use local image would like this :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/icorner/wallpaper/curr.jpg
```

but if i use something like this wont work

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

where `picture-uri` is URL of some image on internet.

Thanks & regards,
Yan Fachmi

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could make it a two step process:

```
wget url_of_image -O wallpaper.jpg
gsettings set ....
```

Comment: ------------------

Comment: i used bash command...and put on startup

anyway thanks for everything....
!/bin/bash

echo "Open Change Wallpaper" cd .. rm /home/icorner/wallpaper/curr.jpg cd /home/icorner/wallpaper wget ftp://XXXX@ftp.XXX.com/wallpaper_warnet/curr.jpg gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/icorner/wallpaper/curr.jpg echo "Done change wallpaper"